# Angularjs CORS HTTP only sometimes sends Options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I realize this is a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue (cross origin resource sharing), however none of the other answers on this site have actually given a real answer, only partials.

[JSONP Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hF5MB/) code in case it disappears:
html:

```
<div ng-app="test">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in people">
            {{person.name}}
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
            $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com?rows=10&name={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
                success(function(data){
                    console.log('jsonp: ' + data.toSource())
                    $scope.people=data;
                });
        });
```

[GET Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE7x7/), **this works on the jsfiddle site (sends OPTIONS and GET), when running from my local instance I only have the GET with an aborted status why?**

html (same as above)

js:

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
            $http.get('http://filltext.com?rows=10&name={firstName}').
                success(function(data){
                    console.log('get: ' + data.toSource())
                    $scope.people=data;
                });
        });
```

curl output for filltext.com:

```
C:\curl>curl -I -L filltext.com  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Content-Length: 0  
Content-Type: text/html  
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept  
Set-Cookie:   ARRAffinity=fe3393d4a10cdae36cc37fe2cf3d22e22d54b3e9d480133b259cf01a6b50cf18;Path=/;Domain=filltext.com  
Set-Cookie: WAWebSiteSID=799ddfe9633c490a8bca027fc70cf991; Path=/; HttpOnly  
Date: Sun, 17 Nov 2013 15:10:34 GMT
```

Firebug output:

[image]

**EDIT**
My environment is a vanilla Apache deployment, with only

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

being the only change.

Comment: did you try in another browser? Might also add $http error handler and look for clues

Comment: @charlietfl doesn't work in any browser I've used (chrome,IE 11, IE 10, FF)

Comment: just for clarification...running from localhost, not direct file open correct?

Comment: @charlietfl yes from localhost.

Comment: @charlietfl I set my apache config to allow Origin of *.  But beyond that it is a vanilla apache deployment.

Comment: very strange...I do lots and lots of ajax local, never run into this before

Comment: @charlietfl  What was most confusing is the instant abort.